# How could I make multiple enemy combat in a C# console game?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on a console game to learn stuff, and I have a combat system in place but I want to make something Final Fantasy like where you fight more than one enemy.

Right now I have this:

```
public void randomEncounter()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        enemy = null;
        int enemyType = rand.Next(1, 4);

        switch (enemyType)
        {
            case 1:
                enemy = new Enemy("Troll", 1, this);
                enemy.setExpGiven(rand.Next(20, 30));
                Console.WriteLine($"A troll appears. \n");
                break;
            case 2:
                enemy = new Enemy("Orc", 1, this);
                enemy.setExpGiven(rand.Next(30, 50));
                Console.WriteLine($"A orc appears. \n");
                break;
            case 3:
                enemy = new Enemy("Ogre", 1, this);
                enemy.setExpGiven(rand.Next(50, 70));
                Console.WriteLine($"A ogre appears. \n");
                break;
        }
    }
```

And here is the menu where I handle the encounter:

```
public void encounterMenu()
    {
        randomEncounter();
        do
        {
            drawHealth();

            Console.WriteLine("1.   Fight");
            Console.WriteLine("2.    Heal ");
            Console.WriteLine("3.  Level Up");
            Console.WriteLine("4.   Flee \n");

            try
            {
                Console.Write("What do you wish to do? : ");
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        fight();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        heal();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        player.levelUp();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Clear();
                        mainMenu();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice! \n");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNo choice entered! \n");
            }

            pause();
            Console.Clear();

            if(enemy.isDead())
            {
                randomEncounter();
            }
        } while (choice != 0);
    }
```

And I tried making a random gen for the number of enemies and and their type, and it would work fine, but with just one enemy it would break, the menu would not draw, you could not attack etc.

Comment: Please show us how you “tried making a random gen” and explain what “with just enemy it would break” means.

Comment: Well It would break with just one enemy, that was a typo sorry. And I had a random gen that would decide how many enemies would spawn , and they were handled by a nested switch that would go and get a random type for every enemy (1, 2 or 3 enemies). I don't have that code because I have deleted it because I got frustrated.

Answer (score 3):

Writing your entire program is beyond the scope of what Stack Overflow can provide, but I can offer some general advice.

Beginners often get stuck because they haven't broken their problem down into solvable steps. In programming, you typically break a problem into steps by creating classes. You have created a class for enemies, but if you want to “make something ... where you fight more than one enemy” you have to create a class for that.

```
public class Encounter
{
    Player player;
    IEnumerable<Enemy> enemies;

    public Encounter(Player player)
    {
        if (player == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(player));

        this.player = player;
        enemies = new List<Enemy>();
    }
}
```

Now instead of fighting enemies you fight encounters:

```
var encounter = new Encounter(player);
```

You have many undefined identifiers in your example. I'm guessing those are static variables. You should not be using those, you should be making class variables and methods; your `encounterMenu` method should look more like this:

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        player.Attack(encounter);
        encounter.Attack(player);
        break;

    case 2:
        encounter.Attack(player);
        player.Heal();
        break;

}
```

You should also not be hard-coding Console commands in your logic. If you need to print a name or prompt your should be doing that in your UI:

```
Console.WriteLine($"A {encounter.name} appears!");
```